# How to set <a> tag in <kbd> by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gsp with html code as below

```
<div class="custom-indicators-row-one">
    <div class="indicator-1 pull-left" >
        <kbd></kbd>
    </div>
```

How can I use JavaScript to set `<a>` inside `<kbd>` so I can define a url in it?

I had done it like this in JavaScript

```
$element.html(indic.link(url));
```

where `$element` is referring to `<kbd>`, `indic` is a value and `url` is to be opened when the value clicked. I noticed by this method I have the url open in new tab or can't change the color of the font.

Comment: What do you mean by _"define a uril in it"_? Do you mean just put text inside the element: eg `<kbd>http://some.url</kbd>`?

Comment: Post a fiddle/snippet, it would be easier to work with. Also why do you want to put an `a` within `kbd`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes i want to do so using javascript but I need to make the link open in new tab. So I thought I required _blank in <a> tag to make it possible.

Comment: Not clear at all what you are asking. Suggest reading [ask] and provide explicit  details in the question. Sounds like all you want is to append an `<a>` which isn't hard to research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to set `<a>` tag inside `<kbd>`

```
var kbd = document.getElementsByTagName('kbd')[0];
kbd.innerHTML = '<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">Click me</a>';
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5caps8f3/

Comment: That is what exactly I need. Thanks alot. Also do you know how I can change the default color of hyperlink displayed via this way?

Comment: You can use this CSS
`kbd a {
  color : red;
}`